# Burning a match in a one-exit tunnel (or Heavy Rain trial of the butterfly scene)

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry

If you light a match in a narrow labyrinth tunnel where there is only one way the air is coming from, will the flame of a match bend in that direction?

In other words, I want to know if the trick one of the characters used to find a way out in the game Heavy Rain is possible in real life scenario.

Here is a video clip for reference: https://youtu.be/67Y3krXsMrM?t=245

Comment: I don't know the whole scene, but air doesn't move unless something _makes_ it move. If the thing making the air move is inside the labyrinth, then the flame will only lead you in circles. If the thing making the air move is outside the labyrinth, then there must be more than one opening; at least one where the air enters, and at least one other where the air leaves. If there's only one opening, and there's nothing inside the labyrinth that circulates the air, then the air will be still, and the flame won't lead you anywhere.

Comment: Also note: If you are ever trapped in a similar situation, and there _is_ a breeze that you can follow, you should be prepared for the possibility that the air is coming in from the same opening that you entered, and it is going out through openings that are too small for you to fit through. The flame could lead you away from the entrance instead of toward it.

Comment: A temperature differential (hot air near the ceiling) could potentially lead to a current being generated - the air would need to come in cold and flow out warm - all through the same opening. There'd be turbulence to account for, confusing the direction of flow.